# Why @Body() in Post request is not working properly? [Nest.js]

Tags: nestjs

I'm starting to learn Nest.js, so I am following an Academind Tutorial ([link](https://youtu.be/F_oOtaxb0L8?t=2249)).

My code is not working as expected when I try to get the `body` variable with the `@Body()` decorator in the `POST` request. Following this part of the code in `products.controller.ts`

```
@Post()
async addProduct(@Body() body: Product) {
  console.log(body);
  const generatedId = this.productService.insertProduct(body.title, body.description, 5.99);
  return generatedId;
}
```

In the terminal the output is just an empty object: `{}`

I have searched for other examples to look at how to do it properly. I found [a tutorial in DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/getting-started-with-nestjs) where they also use `@Body` in the POST request; they leave a the end of the tutorial [a repo with the example](https://github.com/yemiwebby/bookstore-nest). This example is neither working for me.

I just did a small change in `addBook()` function on `book.service.ts` file for returning the new book instead of all books

```
addBook(book): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        this.books.push(book);
        // resolve(this.books);
        resolve(book);
    });
}
```

I do the following POST request from Postman but an empty object is being the response.

[image: POST request from Postman]

All other HTTP requests are working just nice, except for the POST one.

Any ideas what could be wrong with the code? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You're sending `form-data` which NestJS does not correctly parse by default. You can use `application/x-www-url-form-encoded` or `application/json` along with the `raw` option in Postman. The JSON body would look like so:

```
{
  "id": "7",
  "title": "Whatever Title",
  "desscription": "whats doc",
  "author": "Me"
}
```

And then your server will recognize the body properly. The other option would be to add in a body parser that properly parses form-data. There are several options out there like `multer`, `form-parser`, `formidable`, and others.

Comment: that was helpful, resolved the issue I was facing.

Comment: This resolved the issue. I was facing the similar issue while creating a post request in PostMan.

Comment: Is there any way to send data as form?

Comment: You need to use `multer` to parse the `multipart/form-data`, either with the `FileInterceptor` or `AnyFileInterceptor` if you don't plan on actually sending a file

Comment: Facing the same issue while testing an api from AWS lambda console. But when I use a custom validation pipe, I am able to receive the body.

Comment: @JayMcDoniel if I cannot change how the request, can I still get the body with changes in nestjs setup? I am sending the request from aws lambda console and cannot control the behaviour of the body being received in multiValueQueryStringParameters section of lambda event.

Answer (score 7):

Not related to the example but related to the title.

If you use ValidationPipe with whitelist=true on your app.

```js
app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe({ whitelist: true }));
```

whitelist — removes any property of query that is not part of DTO.

And do not use decorators from the 'class-validator' on your DTO object

```js
import { IsNotEmpty, MaxLength } from 'class-validator';

export class Cat {
  @MaxLength(200)
  @IsNotEmpty()
  name: string;

  age: number; // would be removed by ValidationPipe when whitelist=true
}
```

The properties would be removed. And you will get the empty object.

Comment: This is useful! Another colleague added this to our project and basically broke post end points using the Body attribute. It took me a while to find out why and this helped

Answer (score 1):

i also faced the same issue, first i tried to send the data as **raw** format but it didn't worked properly, then i used **x-www-urlencoded** tab on postman and it solved the issue for me.

Edit: i had a typo in **raw** format, now it's working fine!

Answer (score 1):

Remove the type (Product) for body works for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Product must be a DTO and have class-validator in it. Please try it, It worked for me.